# Spawning multiple nodejs threads from single javascript file

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am new to nodejs and javascript. Could anyone advice me on how I can spawn multiple nodejs threads from one javascript file? I will need to pass in the port number while spawning the nodejs threads. Currently, I wrote a batch file to do this.

```
@echo off

set numberOfThreads= %1 
set portNumberToStart = %2
echo step1 %numberOfThreads%
:loop
if %numberOfThreads%==0 (goto :eof) else (start node . portNumberToStart)
set /a numberOfThreads=%numberOfThreads%-1
echo loop %numberOfThreads%
goto :loop
```

Comment: Do you want to spawn multiple node.js workers listening for the same TCP port?

Comment: Looks like you're looking for [node.js Cluster feature](http://nodejs.org/api/cluster.html).